# How to make 2 inline divs, one with the width of its content, second with the width of remaining space of the parent

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I am struggling with using flexbox to achieve that

This code is quite self explaining

```
<div id="inlineWrapper">
    <div class="widthOfTheContent">Some label</div>
    <div class="widthOfRemainingSpace"> <input class="width-100"/> </div>
</div>
```

I tried to play with flexbox but could not figure out how to make the first inline div to take the width of the content

Comment: I think [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is able to help you in this ocasions. I hope is useful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
#inlineWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.widthOfTheContent {
  background: tomato;
}

.widthOfRemainingSpace {
  flex: auto;
  background: lemonchiffon;
}
.width-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="inlineWrapper">
    <div class="widthOfTheContent">Some label</div>
    <div class="widthOfRemainingSpace"> <input class="width-100"/> </div>
</div>
```

You just need to set the `widthOfRemainingSpace` to `flex: auto` or `flex:1`

Comment: What's the difference between flex:auto or flex:1 if both are supposed to work the same way there?

Comment: @BartłomiejSobieszek flex:auto is just a shorthand for flex: 1 1 auto. it means the element will absorb any remaining space. flex: 1 is shorthand for flex: 1 1 0. The 3rd parameter is flex-basis, it means that the element has no starting starting value. You don't need the starting value here because your input element has a width of 100%

Answer (score 1):

You just need `flex:1` on the element you want to fill the space:

```
#inlineWrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.widthOfRemainingSpace {
  flex: 1;
}

.widthOfRemainingSpace input {
  width:100%;
}
```

Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/doughballs/pen/KKdoXOr).